# Segmentation fault after aplying the function : !dataValida

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault

After I implement the function dataValida that checks if the date on the csv column is set on dd/mm/yyyy ( the only errors that can occur are like: 25/12/2010  15:01:56 or  1978|04|30), the program gives a segmentation fault.

When I run the program it shows this:  (before that it used to show the printf's in the right way, including the examples)

```
File opened with success
Parsing Concluded
Segmentation fault
```

I already tried to redo the function in different ways and it still gets the same error. Besides that, it also occurs when I try to do other functions to check if the "estado" is either active or inactive.

Could anyone help me here please?

(the "contemArrobba" and "paisValido" are working just fine)

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char* id;
    char* nome;
    char* email;
    char* tele;
    char* data;
    char sexo;
    char* passaporte;
    char* pais;
    char* morada;
    char* cria_conta;
    char* pagamento;
    char* estado;
} User;

void freeUser(User *user) {
    // Esta função libera todos os campos de string alocados dinamicamente de um User->
    free(user->id);
    free(user->nome);
    free(user->email);
    free(user->data);
    free(user->passaporte);
    free(user->pais);
    free(user->morada);
    free(user->cria_conta);
    free(user->pagamento);
    free(user->estado);
}

int dataValida(const char *data) {
    if (strlen(data) != 10) return 0; // Verifica o comprimento da string

    // Verifica se os caracteres nas posições corretas são barras ('/')
    return data[2] == '/' && data[5] == '/';
}

int contemArroba(const char *str) {
    return strchr(str, '@') != NULL; // Retorna 1 se contém '@', senão retorna 0
}

int paisValido(const char* country) {
    return (strcmp(country, "PT") == 0); // Retorna 1 se o país for "PT", caso contrário 0
}

//  while (!feof(file))
User** organizaUser(FILE *file, int* n_user_out){
    char *linha = NULL;
    size_t tamanho = 0;
    ssize_t valido;

    int linhas = 0;
    User **users = NULL;
    int n_user = 0;

    while ((valido = getline(&linha, &tamanho, file)) != -1) {

        if(linhas == 0) {
            linhas++;
            continue;
        }
        //  user = realloc(users, (n_user + 1) * sizeof(User));

        char *token = strtok(linha, ";");
        if (token == NULL) continue;

        User *newUser = malloc(sizeof(User)); // Aloca memória para um novo User
        if (newUser == NULL) {
            // Tratar erro de alocação
            break;
        }
        *newUser = (User){0};
        newUser->id = strdup(token);
        
        token = strtok(NULL, ";");

        if (token == NULL) {
            free(newUser->id);
            continue;
        }

        newUser->nome = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL) {
            free(newUser->id);
            free(newUser->nome);
            continue;
        }

        newUser->email = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL || !contemArroba(newUser->email)) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }

        newUser->tele = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL|| !dataValida(token) ) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }

        newUser->data = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }
        newUser->sexo = token[0];

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }
        newUser->passaporte = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }
        newUser->pais = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL || !paisValido(newUser->pais)) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }
        newUser->morada = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }    
        newUser->cria_conta = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }   
        newUser->pagamento = strdup(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        if (token == NULL ) {
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            continue;
        }            
        newUser->estado = strdup(token);

  
        User **temp = realloc(users, (n_user + 1) * sizeof(User*));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            // Se realloc falhar, libere os recursos alocados e retorne
            // Aqui você deve liberar os campos de newUser que já foram alocados
            freeUser(newUser);
            free(newUser);
            break;
        }
        users = temp;
        // Prosseguir com a atribuição dos demais campos de newUser (nome, email, data, sexo, passaporte, pais, morada, cria_conta, pagamento, status)
        users[n_user] = newUser;

        if (n_user == 11) {
            printf("Usuer 12 (estado): %s\n", newUser->estado);
        }


        n_user++;
        linhas++;

        *n_user_out = n_user;
    }

    free(linha); // Liberar a memória alocada pela getline

    return users; // Retorna o ponteiro para o array de User
} 

int main(void) {

    FILE *file = fopen("/home/rafaelsilva/Projeto/dataset/data/users.csv", "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open the file.\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("File opened with sucess.\n");
    }

    int num_users;

    User **users = organizaUser(file, &num_users);

    fclose(file);
    printf("Parsing Concluded.\n");

    printf("The id of the user 9301 : %s\n", users[9300]->id);    

    for (int i = 0; i < num_users; i++) {
        freeUser(users[i]);
        free(users[i]);
    }
    free(users);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: My advice would be to run the code in a debugger and when it crashes examine the callstack and the variables to figure out why.

Comment: What did you find after debugging it?

Comment: @TheNomad how can I debug it?

Comment: @RetiredNinja how can I debug it?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Use a debugger, like GDB.

Comment: Are you sure there are at least 9301 users in the file? What's the value of `num_users`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. The file that I'm using has 10000 users but we are suposed to create a program that can read any limit of users. If I try to run the program without the dataValida function, it shows me the right user at 9301.

I already runned it with GDB, I'm kind noob at it but I guess it didn't show me anything.

It's just so weird because every other function that I create to check the other values (like date, or the status of the account) it gets the same error.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I already runned it with GDB, I'm kind noob at it but I guess it didn't show me anything.

Comment: @TheNomad  I already runned it with GDB, I'm kind noob at it but I guess it didn't show me anything.

Comment: It sounds like `dataValida()` is returning `false`, so some of the users in the file are being skipped. Try printing something when you skip a user because of this. I'll ask again: What is the valud of `num_users`?

Comment: @Barmar I'm starting num_users as 0.
When I read one line in the CSV that is done right, it increments the value of num_users. In the CSV that I'm using, the max number of users is 10001.

I can't print anything because it gives me that segmentation fault. Even the line:
  if (n_user == 11)  printf("Usuário 12 (estado): %s\n", newUser->estado);

isn't printing. Even if I change the n_user==1, it won't print a thing

Comment: What is the actual value of `num_users` when you get the error? Put `printf("num_users = %d\n", num_users);` after parsing concluded.

Comment: You're getting the segmentation fault when you try to access `users[9300]->id`. You should be able to print something before that.

Comment: @Barmar when I do that printf, it prints that num_users = 9

Comment: Well, there you have it. Almost all users are failing the validation check.

Comment: @Barmar so how I can I fix this? I don't understand where the error is

Comment: Try printing `token` when the validation fails, so you can see what values in the file are causing the failure.

Comment: @Barmar I did some testing and if I print the n_user == 8, it jumps to the person on the position 9594 on my CSV, I don't know why it is passing all those people.

Comment: Obviously the sexo field of those records is not formatted the way your validation function expects. Without seeing a sample of the file I can't be more specific.

Comment: @Barmar where do you want me to send you the file?

Comment: Just add the first 10 lines to the question in a code block. That should be enough to see the problem, since only 8 lines are valid.

Comment: Or just learn to use a debugger. Put a breakpoint in the `if` block after calling `dataValida()`. Then you can print `token` to see what it is.

Comment: @Barmar added it

Comment: All the `sex` fields are just `F` or `M`. `dataValida()` requires 10 characters with `/` in character 2 and 5. I think that's supposed to be used for the `birth_date` field, not sex.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but isn't the dataValida() being used to check the newUser->data ?

Comment: no. You're using it *after* you call `strtok()` to get the next field.

Comment: @Barmar I changed it now (I edited the code above) and it still shows the exact same output in the terminal when I run it.

Comment: `return data[2] == '/' && data[5] == '/';` should be be checking indices 4 & 7 for `/` since the dates are in `YYYY/MM/DD` format. `freeUser` is also missing `free(user->tele);`. https://godbolt.org/z/hnMjePoGr

Comment: @HelpMe I'm worried there are more problems then you assume. My first red flag is your initial statement `dataValida that checks if the date on the csv collumn is set on dd/mm/yyyy ( the only errors that can occur are like: 25/12/2010 15:01:56 or 1978|04|30)` but we already see the CSV is packed with `YYYY/MM/DD`. Either you misunderstood the request, either the export was wrong and you need to decide how to proceed further. Because at this rate you'll change the program on every export. Also, **remember to delete the csv from the post once you solve it**. There's a ton of personal data there.

Comment: @HelpMe Good job! I see you also deleted the CSV. If Allan is the one that solved it for you, please mark his solution as "Accepted", if it isn't, but he only helped, please post an answer with the solution in order to help others.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your program segfaults on the line:

   ```
   printf("The id of the user 9301 : %s\n", users[9300]->id);
   ```

   This is because `users` is NULL.  `users` is NULL as `dataValida()` returns 0 for dates, for example, `1979/11/27` which doesn't match the expected format `data[2] == '/' && data[5] == '/';`.  You fix that with:

   ```
   int dataValida(const char *data) {
       if (strlen(data) != 10) return 0;
       return data[4] == '/' && data[7] == '/';
   }
   ```
2. After this change program segfaults in the same location but now it's because the sample input file contains 11 records and you try to access the array out of bound (9300 > 10).  If I change the print statement to:

   ```
    printf("The id of the user 9301 : %s\n", users[num_users-1]->id);
   ```

   It now correctly prints out the id of the last record.
3. Bonus: You fix the memory leak by adding `free(user->tele)` to `freeUser()`:

   ```
   void freeUser(User *user) {
       free(user->id);
       free(user->nome);
       free(user->email);
       free(user->data);
       free(user->passaporte);
       free(user->pais);
       free(user->morada);
       free(user->cria_conta);
       free(user->pagamento);
       free(user->estado);
       free(user->tele);
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you allan! it really helped me a lot :)

Comment: My pleasure.  If that answered your question please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.